# need to delete bulk insert object to run again

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

i have a sql script I am supposed to run that starts with:

```
    BULK INSERT #BridgeVendors
    FROM 'D:\projects\databases\Scripts\Release\6.7.1\BridgeVendors.csv'
    WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR=',', FIRSTROW = 2 )
```

the first time I ran it I had the path name going toincorrect path so it didn't execute properly , but now - I can't run it again because I get the error :

> There is already an object named '#BridgeVendors' in the database.

How do I *UNDO* or DELETE this "Object" that was a BULK INSERT??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to drop the table :)

```
drop table #BridgeVendors
```

Comment: that was stupid easy - sorry I was a little confused

Comment: that's OK, here is the place to get answers ... happy code!

Comment: I tried Select [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From Sys.Objects where
 [Name] like '%BridgeVendors%'  and it couldn't find , so I thought this was something more complex. just just regular drop table worked fine

Comment: This was because you are inserting in a temporary table. The # in front of the name determine it as temporary.

to list temporary objects you can use this query:
select * from tempdb.sys.objects